# Can you access strings by indices (indexes) in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans-7

For example:

```
String word = "schnucks";
word[1] = 'x'; // would this access the C and turn it to an x?
```

If the above code is not correct, is there a way, besides converting it from a string to a char array to access the individual indices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings in Java are immutable. You can read a char from a specific index with [`charAt(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) but you can not modify it. For that you would need to convert to a char array as you suggested and then build a new string from the array.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `replace()`:

```
String word = "schnucks";
word = word.replace("c", "x");//<-- "sxhnucks", only first occurrence
```

Also there is `replaceAll()`:

```
String word = "schnucks";
word = word.replaceAll("c", "x");//<-- "sxhnuxks", all occurrences
```

Answer (score 2):

To access the elements of a `String` by index, first convert to an array of `char`s.

```
String word = "schnucks";
char[] array = word.toCharArray();
```

Then you are free to change any letter as you wish. e.g.

```
array[4] = 'a';
```

To retrieve the modified `String`, simply use

```
word = new String(array);
```

which returns a `String` containing the word `schnacks`.

Answer (score 0):

well you can use `charAt(int index)` method to access character at your specified index.

But for changing characters of the string you can use **StringBuilder** class and use `.setCharAt(int index, char character)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change characters in a String because Strings are immutable in Java.

As mentioned in the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created.

To read a character from a String, use [charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))

> Returns the char value at the specified index. An index ranges from 0 to length() - 1.

To get a String with only a certain character changed, you can do as follows:

```
String word = "geography";
int indexToChange = 3;
char newCharacter = 'x';
String newword = word.substring(0, indexToChange - 1) + newCharacter + word.substring(indexToChange, word.length());
System.out.println(newword);
```